# How to run a test in loop based on the index of the objects returned by fixture in Cypress.io?

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, cypress

I need to run a test 'n' times based on the number of objects returned by the fixture in Cypress.io. I am using forEach method exposed by Cypress for looping. I am using the forEach loop in the outer space of the 'it' command but inside describe. I am getting an undefined error on the fixture object.
See the code below:

```
describe("Search by people returns expected result", () => {

before(() => {
    cy.fixture('people').then(function(peopleJson) {
        this.peopleJson = peopleJson;
    });
    cy.fixture('planets').then(function(planetsJson) {
        this.planetsJson = planetsJson;
    });
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/')
});

this.peopleJson.forEach(data => {
    it('Verify people by'+ data.name, function() {
        cy.searchBy('people', data.name)
        cy.verifyPerson(data)
    })
})

afterEach(() => {
    cy.log("inside aftereach!")
    clearForm();
})});
```

> Error message that I am getting in Cypress compiler is
>
> The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
>
> > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'peopleJson')
>
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code
> it will automatically fail the current test.
>
> Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
>
> We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

**`this.peopleJson`** is undefined right now but if I take the forEach loop inside the 'if' block then the code is working. But I want to dynamically generate the test cases and also so that if any test case fails for any data object then the test continues for others.

I tried the other way to put the fixture command right above the forEach but that didn't work either. I referred to the original documentation of Cypress.io and I found that a fixture call must be part of It block so I can't use fixture just above the forEach loop.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

People.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "R2-D2",
        "gender": " n/a ",
        "birthYear": " 33BBY ",
        "eyeColor": " red ",
        "skinColor": " white, blue ",
        "description": "name with numbers"
    },
    {
        "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        "gender": " male ",
        "birthYear": " 57BBY ",
        "eyeColor": " blue-gray ",
        "skinColor": " fair ",
        "description": "name with dash and space"
    },
    {
        "name": "Boba Fett",
        "gender": " male ",
        "birthYear": " 31.5BBY ",
        "eyeColor": " brown ",
        "skinColor": " fair ",
        "description": "name consists of two words"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dormé",
        "gender": " female ",
        "birthYear": " unknown ",
        "eyeColor": " brown ",
        "skinColor": " light ",
        "description": "name with special character"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ki-Adi-Mundi",
        "gender": " male ",
        "birthYear": " 92BBY ",
        "eyeColor": " yellow ",
        "skinColor": " pale ",
        "description":  "name with two dashes"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Rahul. Is your `peopleJson` an object or something else? `forEach` method executes a provided function once for each `array` element, otherwise you need `Object.entries` method to return [key, value] properties before you loop through.

Comment: cy.fixture('people') command is importing a "people.json" file containing an array of 5 elements and assigning it to peopleJson array object.

Comment: @R.Rahul can you add how your json file looks like

Comment: Done, it is added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use the json file outside of `it` block so you cannot use `beforeEach()`. Instead you have to import the json file in your test and apply the forEach

```js
import peopleJson from '../fixtures/people.json' //Assuming your test is inside integration folder

describe('Search by people returns expected result', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/')
  })

  peopleJson.forEach((data) => {
    it('Verify people by' + data.name, function () {
      cy.searchBy('people', data.name)
      cy.verifyPerson(data)
    })
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.log('inside aftereach!')
    clearForm()
  })
})
```

Comment: I didn't want to do that at first. But it solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To use the [`this`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#this-context) keyword you'll have to use a regular function `function () {}` and not fat arrow `() => {}`

```
describe("Search by people returns expected result", () => {
before( function () { // changed to regular function
    cy.fixture('people').then(function(peopleJson) {
        this.peopleJson = peopleJson;
    });
    cy.fixture('planets').then(function(planetsJson) {
        this.planetsJson = planetsJson;
    });
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/')
});

this.peopleJson.forEach(data => {
    it('Verify people by'+ data.name, function() {
        cy.searchBy('people', data.name)
        cy.verifyPerson(data)
    })
})

afterEach(() => {
    cy.log("inside aftereach!")
    clearForm();
})});
```

Comment: jjhelguero-your code isn't going to work as per the question and will fail for the same reason.